# UIPanGestureRecognizer in iOS 4.3 not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a UIImageView subclass and I need to have a pan gesture so I added the following code:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

but my handlePan selector never gets called.

Is there something else i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object is **UIImageView** subclass, you have to enable user interaction. It is set to **NO** by default for **UIImageView**.

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: You are welcome! I have faced this problem several times :) Please check my answer as correct to close this issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried to accept it, but it told me I had to wait 5 minutes... geez your fast, please answer all my questions!!! -:)

Comment: I get it, no problem :) I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I had EXACTLY the same problem using the StoryBoard - I created a sub-view in my main view, dropped a Pan Gesture Recognizer on it, created an action and joined the pan to it, and it didn't work.

My sub-view had User Interaction Enabled on it and it didn't work.  Frustrated, I deleted my Pan Gesture, added it back, everything seemed hooked up and it still didn't work.

Finally, I looked at the SUPERVIEW and its User Interaction Enabled was checked off.  Checking it on and it worked.

So as a caveat, if it's not working, look at the parent views too!